# cf_ct_date_input and leap year

Tags: coldfusion

anyone using the cf_ct_date_input tag? If so are you having trouble with the leap year this year. Our calendar only goes through the 28th and I'm not sure how to get it to go through the 29th. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say its buggy and doesn't cater for the proper leap year calculation.

Thus you are probably going to need to modify it yourself or find the developer.

This isn't one of those strange years, its a clear case of being divisible by 4

A year will be a leap year if it is divisible by 4 but not by 100. If a year is divisible by 4 and by 100, it is not a leap year unless it is also divisible by 400.

Comment: That was what we wound up doing.